# java.util.logging check if file exist in java

Tags: java, file, logging

I am using java's `java.util.logging` api for logging messages in my java application.as of now each time file is getting created when application starts. i want to check if file exist then append content to that file

code :

```
public static Logger logger;
static FileHandler fh;

logger = Logger.getLogger("Log");
logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);     

String sFileName = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(new Date());

fh = new FileHandler(sPath + "//" + sFileName + ".txt");
logger.addHandler(fh);

SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
fh.setFormatter(formatter);
```

after this i called below line to get message into `.txt` file

```
Classname.logger.info("---START LOGGING----");
```

As my code does not use `file.open()` method, i cant go for `file.exists()` call.

Comment: Logger.exists is present?

Comment: no it does not have that method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The FileHandler has an option to append to the given file instead of overwriting it.

```
FileHandler(String pattern, boolean append)
    Initialize a FileHandler to write to the given filename, with optional append.
```

So your code would look like this:

```
public static Logger logger;
static FileHandler fh;

logger = Logger.getLogger("Log");
logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);     

String sFileName = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(new Date());

fh = new FileHandler(sPath + "//" + sFileName + ".txt", true);
logger.addHandler(fh);

SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
fh.setFormatter(formatter);
```